# Properties of continuity

Tags: integration, functions, continuity, continued-fractions

Let $f,g :[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that $$\int\limits_c^df(x)\leq \int\limits_c^dg(x)dx$$  whenever a$\leq$c$<$d$\leq$b.

I need to show that $f(x)\leq g(x)$.  I have the idea of using proof by contradiction supposing that $f(x)>g(x)$, but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Then, by continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$ in the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\cap [a,b]$.

Comment: You can also do this directly: to prove continuity at a point k, take c=k-epsilon and d=k+epsilon as epsilon approaches zero and then apply continuity.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help, observe that your hypothesis is equivalent to $0\leq\int^d_c g(x)-f(x)dx$, then show that a continuous function such that $0\leq\int^d_c h(x)dx$ for all $c<d$ must be non-negative (by contradiction).